# How to send file to FTP server using LabVIEW

Tags: ftp, labview

I have to send file to ftp server every time, when the file is upgraded by LabVIEW. I found LabVIEW function 'FTP Put File VI', but the file cannot be sent to server, which has the password. I wouldn't like to use any scripts or external program, if it isn't necessary. Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: What code do you use (screenshot/snippet) and what error code do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If I look at the online help for '[FTP Put File](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/lvcomm/ftp_put_file/)' function it has entries for password and username.
You are even required to insert those details.

[image: FTP Put File]

That should work.

You can even run the FTP Put File VI in stand-alone mode. Open the VI fill in the details and run it, it should finish with status 221 (FTP-Goodby):
Also make sure you can connect to it with another application (command line FTP tool, Total Commander, Firefox, Internet Explorer).

[image: FTP Upload success]

**show what you have tried so far**

Comment: This is what is writen about password in this function:'Password is the password that authenticates the username. (NI Linux Real-Time) You must specify a blank password. For NI Linux Real-Time targets, the FTP server does not accept NI-Auth credentials.'.

Comment: The FTP toolkit uses standard (non-sftp) authentication for the FTP communication (you can drill down into the VIs to look it up. What kind of FTP server is your target? Please show some code and error lines.